# Logitech C920 microphone suddenly stopped working only on my Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound, webcam, microphone, logitech

I have exactly the same question than in the post ["Logitech c920 microphone not working in Ubuntu 18.04"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1128694/logitech-c920-microphone-not-working-in-ubuntu-18-04): my Logitech c920 webcam microphone suddenly stopped working on my ubuntu 18.04

Microphone (input) recognized by the system but not catching any sound. Not hardware issue. When I use it on another device or OS everything is working well.

I tried the proposed solution `modprobe snd_usb_audio`, unfortunately it does not solve the problem for me.

If someone has an idea, I thank you in advance :)

Comment: In Sound settings check if the mic volume is at the minimum or disabled altogether. For some reason, I had a similar issue with my headset.

Comment: Thanks, but checked and volume is ok

Comment: have the same issue but on 20.04. It was working fine for a while and then stopped totally. Works fine on my mac. Still researching.

Comment: it seems either through an update or some other magic, my mic is working on 20.04 perfectly again. It stopped working randomly one day and started working again another!

Answer (score 1):

"Black magic" saves me! ;)
The solution of the question [How to fix internal microphone which stopped working on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1213962/how-to-fix-internal-microphone-which-stopped-working-on-ubuntu-18-04) shared by *Ocean*:

> I had a very similar problem. All the orthodox solutions didn't help. I solved it by fiddling around.
>
> Here's the witchcraft that worked for me:
>
> 1) Connect another external microphone and select it (sound should work)
>   2) Disconnect the microphone you want to get working
>   3) Reconnect the microphone you want to get working
>
> Input sound should now work again for this microphone by the means of black magic.

After a lot of time searching and testing tools, parameters... **it was actually sufficient to plug my earphone and then replug my webcam C920 to solve the problem!** Why not ;) I hope this resharing could help others.

Comment: Too hasty joy... it has worked 2 times, but not anymore. Visibly random and unstable.