# USB webcam microphone not working

Tags: 20.04, usb, webcam, microphone

I have a USB webcam which have inbuilt microphone.. The camera is working and the mic is detected.. but it is not giving any input.

https://www.amazon.in/TVS-WC-103-HD-Webcam-1080Pixel/dp/B08G4X6TC1/ref=asc_df_B08G4X6TC1/?tag=googleshopdes-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=396987037596&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=626450613447870603&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9040216&hvtargid=pla-947225293670&psc=1&ext_vrnc=hi

Output with `pacmd list-sources`

```
3 source(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <alsa_input.usb-Jieli_Technology_USB_PHY_2.0-02.mono-fallback>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE
    priority: 9040
    volume: mono: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 35466 /  54% / -16.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 1ch 44100Hz
    channel map: mono
                 Mono
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    card: 0 <alsa_card.usb-Jieli_Technology_USB_PHY_2.0-02>
    module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "USB Audio"
        alsa.id = "USB Audio"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "2"
        alsa.card_name = "USB PHY 2.0"
        alsa.long_card_name = "Jieli Technology USB PHY 2.0 at usb-0000:02:00.0-6, high speed"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:02:00.0-usb-0:6:1.2"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:02:00.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.2/sound/card2"
        udev.id = "usb-Jieli_Technology_USB_PHY_2.0-02"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "1224"
        device.vendor.name = "Jieli Technology"
        device.product.id = "2a25"
        device.product.name = "USB PHY 2.0"
        device.serial = "Jieli_Technology_USB_PHY_2.0"
        device.form_factor = "webcam"
        device.string = "hw:2"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "176400"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "88200"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "mono-fallback"
        device.profile.description = "Mono"
        device.description = "USB PHY 2.0 Mono"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "camera-web-usb"
    ports:
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
    active port: <analog-input-mic>
    index: 1
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_07_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1.monitor>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE
    priority: 1030
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 1999.82 ms
    monitor_of: 0
    card: 1 <alsa_card.pci-0000_07_00.1>
    module: 8
    properties:
        device.description = "Monitor of GK208 HDMI/DP Audio Controller Digital Stereo (HDMI 2)"
        device.class = "monitor"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xf7080000 irq 77"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:07:00.1"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:07:00.1/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "10de"
        device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
        device.product.id = "0e0f"
        device.product.name = "GK208 HDMI/DP Audio Controller"
        device.string = "0"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    index: 2
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_09_00.4.iec958-stereo.monitor>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE
    priority: 1030
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    fixed latency: 100.14 ms
    monitor_of: 1
    card: 2 <alsa_card.pci-0000_09_00.4>
    module: 9
    properties:
        device.description = "Monitor of Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller Digital Stereo (IEC958)"
        device.class = "monitor"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xf7400000 irq 79"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:09:00.4"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:09:00.4/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "1022"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
        device.product.id = "1487"
        device.product.name = "Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller"
        device.string = "1"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
```

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? The tags show three versions, one of which is EOL. 

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 .

Comment: Can you update your question to include the output of: `pacmd list-sources`? This will show some information about the USB camera's microphone, it's state, and properties.

Comment: Yes i made the edit

Answer (score 8):

Based on the output of `pacmd list-sources`, all of your microphones are suspended for being idle (which makes sense). What I have found with some USB-connected devices is that once the microphone is set to `SUSPENDED` they never come back. There are generally two solutions for this problem:

1. Unplug the webcam, count to five, and plug it back in.
   ⇢ This will cycle the USB device and *generally* brings all of the devices back online.
2. Update PulseAudio to *not* suspend idle audio devices.
   ⇢ This has generally worked well for a number of computers at work where the USB cameras cannot be physically disconnected from the computer without a sharp pair of scissors.

#### Modifying PulseAudio

To prevent audio devices from being suspended when idle, you will need to comment out a single line in the `default.pa` file. These are the steps to follow:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Open the `default.pa` file for editing as `root`:

   ```
   $ sudo vi /etc/pulse/default.pa
   ```

   ***Note:** Feel free to use something other than `vi`. This is more a force of habit than an implicit recommendation for which editor to use.*
2. Find the line that reads `load-module module-suspend-on-idle` and comment it out. This will be about 90% of the way down. Once done, the line should look like this:

   ```
   ### Automatically suspend sinks/sources that become idle for too long
   # load-module module-suspend-on-idle
   ```
3. Restart PulseAudio:

   ```
   $ pulseaudio -k
   ```
4. Confirm your audio devices are operational:

   ```
   pacmd list-sources
   ```

   Check for the USB microphone, which may be at index `0` like it is in the output you provided, and confirm the value of `state`. It should read `IDLE`. When this is being actively used by an application it will change to `RUNNING`, then go back to `IDLE` about 30 seconds after it is no longer in use.

#### Audio Confusion

One additional issue you might see is that an application may not know which microphone to use automatically and, as a result, the input selection will always be empty. To resolve this, open the PulseAudio Volume Control (pavucontrol) application and click on the "Configuration" tab. Set the output to "Analogue Stereo Output":

[image: PulseAudio - Configuration]

Why setting the *output* resolves an issue with *input*, I can only guess at. That said, this solution does work for those rare instances when the computer consistently shows no audio input device.

Comment: Hey there @Matigo, i tried it, but it is not working... sorry for the late replay

Comment: This didn't help. My "Settings for selected device" in Input tab from Sound settings greyed out instead

Answer (score 0):

In Guvcview->AudioControls was set by default as input device-->pulse. i just changed it to hda intel (my sound card) and worked fine!