# Webcam microphone not working [NEXIGO]

Tags: pulseaudio, microphone, webcam

I have a Nexigo N60 1080p FHD Webcam with a built-in microphone. The webcam works fine, but I cannot get the microphone to work.

I have tried commenting out the `module-suspend-on-idle` line in `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and reloading pulseaudio as suggested in this post: [USB webcam microphone not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1311879/usb-webcam-microphone-not-working) .

As a test, I went to https://online-voice-recorder.com/ and Firefox prompts me to allow the webcam microphone, so it is at least recognizing that there is a microphone there. When I click allow and try to record, no audio gets picked up.

[image]

I am on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. My pacmd shows the device in a RUNNING state while it was supposedly recording:

```
$ pacmd list-sources 
2 source(s) available.
    index: 0
        name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1.monitor>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
        flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
        state: IDLE
        suspend cause: (none)
        priority: 1030
        volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
                balance 0.00
        base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
        volume steps: 65537
        muted: no
        current latency: 0.00 ms
        max rewind: 3 KiB
        sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
        channel map: front-left,front-right
                     Stereo
        used by: 0
        linked by: 0
        configured latency: 371.52 ms; range is 0.50 .. 371.52 ms
        monitor_of: 0
        card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1>
        module: 7
        properties:
                device.description = "Monitor of GM107 High Definition Audio Controller [GeForce 940MX] Digital Stereo (HDMI 2)"
                device.class = "monitor"
                alsa.card = "3"
                alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xdf080000 irq 17"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card3"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.vendor.id = "10de"
                device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
                device.product.id = "0fbc"
                device.product.name = "GM107 High Definition Audio Controller [GeForce 940MX]"
                device.string = "3"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
  * index: 1
        name: <alsa_input.usb-HD_WEBCAM_NexiGo_N60_FHD_Webcam_20201218-02.mono-fallback>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
        flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
        state: RUNNING
        suspend cause: (none)
        priority: 9040
        volume: mono: 64562 /  99% / -0.39 dB
                balance 0.00
        base volume: 64562 /  99% / -0.39 dB
        volume steps: 65537
        muted: no
        current latency: 0.04 ms
        max rewind: 0 KiB
        sample spec: s16le 1ch 16000Hz
        channel map: mono
                     Mono
        used by: 1
        linked by: 1
        configured latency: 24.99 ms; range is 4.00 .. 2000.00 ms
        card: 1 <alsa_card.usb-HD_WEBCAM_NexiGo_N60_FHD_Webcam_20201218-02>
        module: 8
        properties:
                alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
                device.api = "alsa"
                device.class = "sound"
                alsa.class = "generic"
                alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
                alsa.name = "USB Audio"
                alsa.id = "USB Audio"
                alsa.subdevice = "0"
                alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
                alsa.device = "0"
                alsa.card = "1"
                alsa.card_name = "NexiGo N60 FHD Webcam"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HD WEBCAM NexiGo N60 FHD Webcam at usb-0000:00:14.0-3, high speed"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:3:1.2"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.2/sound/card1"
                udev.id = "usb-HD_WEBCAM_NexiGo_N60_FHD_Webcam_20201218-02"
                device.bus = "usb"
                device.vendor.id = "1d6c"
                device.vendor.name = "HD WEBCAM"
                device.product.id = "1278"
                device.product.name = "NexiGo N60 FHD Webcam"
                device.serial = "HD_WEBCAM_NexiGo_N60_FHD_Webcam_20201218"
                device.form_factor = "webcam"
                device.string = "hw:1"
                device.buffering.buffer_size = "64000"
                device.buffering.fragment_size = "32000"
                device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
                device.profile.name = "mono-fallback"
                device.profile.description = "Mono"
                device.description = "NexiGo N60 FHD Webcam Mono"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "camera-web-usb"
        ports:
                analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        active port: <analog-input-mic>
```

Is there anything I might be missing?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I'll share my solution, I'm not sure why it worked though.

1. I ran alsamixer from terminal
2. Switched to sound card corresponding to the webcam.
3. Capture setting was at 0, so I just increased it and now it all suddenly works.

Answer (score 1):

As Ian said, `alsamixer` does it.

1. run `$ alsamixer`
2. press `F6`, and select `NexiGo N60 FHD Wencam Audio` from the resulting pop-up menu. Press `Enter`.
3. Press `F4` (or `F5` for all settings, which is just `Capture` anyway).
4. If it's at 0, raise it to 100 and try the mic out again. If it's not at zero, then... perhaps you have other compatibility issues.
5. Once the `Capture` setting is no longer at 0, you can simply exit with `ESC`.

While I'm sure you've solved your issue already, I'm adding my response here anyway in case anyone else comes across this in the future!